# Can Chrome extensions change page appearance without modifying HTML?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to know whether the APIs available to Google Chrome extensions enable changes the appearance (colors, styles, etc.) of page contents without modifying the HTML?

For example, when spelling or grammar support is enabled, Chrome will underline phrases that contain problems.  The browser doesn't appear to change the markup of the page to accomplish this.  Does the extensions API have that kind of feature?

I'm thinking of writing a sort of writing assistant extension that would behave similarly to the spelling or grammar checkers.  I'd like my extension's display to be similar to those checkers.